# How to call function inside linq anonymous function

Tags: .net, linq, c#-4.0, anonymous-function

I want to do something like that:

```
var result = genericList.ToDictionary(CalculateSomething(x => x.Date), y => y.Point);
```

So according with that example i want to call `CalculateSomething()` inside `.ToDictionary()`

is there any ways i can do that, i may do that through `foreach` loop but i would like to keep `linq` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just got your lambda syntax wrong:

```
var result = genericList.ToDictionary(x => CalculateSomething(x.Date), y => y.Point);
```

Comment: And **1** second off. Spooky.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = genericList.ToDictionary(x => CalculateSomething(x.Date), y => y.Point);
```